# Does IONIC 1 support iOS12?

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, xcode10.2

We have mobile application developed into IONIC 1. It is working fine with Android OS, but it is not working on iOS 12 devices. We are able to build an IPA file using XCode 10 with valid distribution certificate and provision profile. Once app is installed into iphone and open, it disappeared.

On simulator, I have tried with .app file, it is showing below log on service log service of an emulator.

```
UIKitApplication:{bundleId}
Program specified by service does not contain any valid architectures for this system.

services excited with abnormal code:78
```

Looking for solution

Comment: Actually it's cordova that does the compilation, not Ionic, I would rather suspect the cordova version (which one is it, btw?). Also, as a test, does a simple cordova sample application run on your iOS12 device?

Comment: @Kaddath 
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1).
I checked sample application build in IONIC 1 and Cordova 8.1.2 version but it is giving same error

Comment: and with a cordova app without ionic?

Comment: sudo ionic start ionic1Test --type ionic1
using above command

Comment: Yes but what i meant is when you create a basic cordova app without Ionic, does it work? something like `sudo cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld`

Comment: i tried with above command but getting same error. even i used cordova-ios@4.4.0 to support ionic1

Comment: So the problem come from cordova-ios@4.4.0.. If you find a solution i'm highly interested that you post it, because we have a re-usable mobile app base written in Ionic 1 an would prefer not to rewrite it if we need to do a new mobile app

Comment: I found the resolution for this issue.
It seems the issue was with CT signature issue.
Posting the resolution, so it might help someone.
In Keychain Access, I set the trust settings to “Use System Defaults” for the following certificates:
Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Developer ID Certification Authority
iPhone Developer: {email}
iOS Distribution
After this, in XCode do clean build for the project. Also restart XCode.

Comment: Nice, you should actually post this as an answer, many people don't read comments at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the resolution for this issue. It seems the issue was with CT signature issue. Posting the resolution, so it might help someone. In Keychain Access, I set the trust settings to “Use System Defaults” for the following certificates: Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority Developer ID Certification Authority iPhone Developer: {email} iOS Distribution After this, in XCode do clean build for the project. Also restart XCode